# Doubly Linked List

Tags: java, data-structures

I've been trying to figure out how to reverse the order of a doubly-linked 
 list.I've recently made an account on hackerrank and this was my 10th problem.
 It took me 1 hour to figure out the solution (I used pen and paper and tried 
 many times) and finally it passed as correct.
 After that, I saw some answers submitted my some other folks.Their code was 
 very small in length in comparison to mine or you think my answer is also okay.
 I have no one to ask to so I came here...
 I feel dumb when I see that.Can I improve it in future??
 (forgive me if you think this is a dumb 
 question)

```
    Node Reverse(Node head) {
     Node prevNode = null;
     Node NextNode = null;
     Node m = head;
     Node upComingNode = null;
     Node temp = head;
     if(head == null){
      return head;
  }
    else{
        while(temp!=null){
            NextNode = temp.next;
            temp.next = prevNode;
            m.prev = upComingNode;
            prevNode = temp;
            upComingNode = prevNode.next;
            m = temp;
            temp = NextNode;  
        }
       head = prevNode;
    }
    return head;


}
```

Comment: Seems like you got the right idea... even though the code is a bit messy. You can also just check here for a tidy answer: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-a-doubly-linked-list/

Comment: Please add a tag of the programing language you are using.

Comment: This code is written in java

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what language you are working in, but to reverse a doubly linked list you, in brief, you want to swap your next and prev nodes for each node. This can be done fairly shortly and the pseudocode is below:

```
while(currNode != tail){
    currNode.nextNode = tempNode
    currNode.nextNode = currNode.prevNode
    currNode.prevNode = tempNode
    currNode = currNode.prevNode
}
```

Note that we set the next node to iterate on as the *previous* node, since the previous node is actually pointing to the next node now that we made the switch.